# Creating a table in code behind

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, foreach, listitem, sharepoint-list

Hi I have a webpart where I create a table in code behind to display the values of list items for an "Awards" list in a two colum table where each award is displayed side by side in tow columns. I am using a foreach loop to get all the list item values and and at the same time generate the table.

The problem is that for some reason not all list item values are being displayed. Also the list items values are being repeated in the output. Below is a snipped of the code I currenlty have:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(webUrl))
{
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{

try
{

SPList awardsList = web.Lists["Awards"];

SPListItemCollection listItemCollection = awardsList.Items;

int modCounter = 0;
foreach (SPListItem oListItem in listItemCollection)
{
modCounter += 1;

awardYear = oListItem["Year"].ToString();
awardCategory = oListItem["Category"].ToString();
awardNomWon = oListItem["NominatedWon"].ToString();
awardLogo = oListItem["Logo"].ToString(); //need to fingure out how to display images

Table tbl = new Table();
TableRow tblRow = new TableRow();
TableCell tblCellLeft = new TableCell(); //for the awards in the first column
TableCell tblCellRight = new TableCell(); //for the awards in the second column

tblCellLeft.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
tblCellLeft.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
tblCellLeft.CssClass = ("style5");

tblCellRight.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
tblCellRight.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;


//values for the left column
tblCellLeft.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"style1\">" + awardYear +
"</div>"));

tblCellLeft.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"style2\">" + awardCategory + 
"</div>"));

tblCellLeft.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"style3\">" + awardNomWon + 
"</div>"));

//Values for the right column
tblCellRight.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"style1\">" + awardYear + 
"</div>"));

tblCellRight.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"style2\">" + awardCategory 
+ "</div>"));

tblCellRight.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"style3\">" + awardNomWon + 
"</div>"));

tblCellRight.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"style4\">" + "<img src=" + 
awardLogo.Replace(",", "") + "</div>"));

//adding Rows
tblRow.Cells.Add(tblCellLeft);
tblRow.Cells.Add(tblCellRight);
tbl.Rows.Add(tblRow);

if (modCounter % 2 == 0)
{                            
//values from tblCellLeft
PlaceHolder6.Controls.Add(tbl);
}
else
{
//values from the tblRightCell
PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(tbl);
}

}

}
catch (Exception err)
{
PlaceHolder3.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(err.ToString()));
}

}
}


});
```

I am not sure what the problem is. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solved this by using a for loop instead as follows:

```
//getting the awards list and extracting correct values from the necesary fields
//asp running with elevated privilegs
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{

using (SPSite site = new SPSite(webUrl))
{
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{



try
{

SPList awardsList = web.Lists["Awards"];

SPListItemCollection listItemCollection = awardsList.Items;


//getting all list items and displaying them next to each other row by row


//int modCounter = 0;

//Creating the table
Table tbl = new Table();

//foreach (SPListItem oListItem in listItemCollection)
int x = listItemCollectionI.Count;
for(int i = 0; (i * 2) < x; i++) // divide total item collection by two, each loop 
iteration, add two awards to a row (left cell, right cell)
{
// get listItemCollection[i];
//Create table rows, table cells

int leftIndexer = i * 2;
int rightIndexer = (i * 2) + 1;

if (leftIndexer == x)
{
break;
}                                

TableRow tblRow = new TableRow();
TableCell tblCellLeft = new TableCell(); //for the awards in the first column
TableCell tblCellRight = new TableCell(); //for the awards in the second column

tblCellLeft.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
tblCellLeft.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
tblCellLeft.CssClass = ("style5");

tblCellRight.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
tblCellRight.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;


// get the values
awardYear = listItemCollection[leftIndexer]["Title"].ToString();
awardCategory = listItemCollection[leftIndexer]["Category"].ToString();
awardNomWon = listItemCollection[leftIndexer]["NominatedWon"].ToString();
if(listItemCollection[leftIndexer]["Logo"] != null)
awardLogo = (string)listItemCollection[leftIndexer]["Logo"];

// add to left cell
//values for the left column
tblCellLeft.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"style1\">" + awardYear + 
"</div>"));
tblCellLeft.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"style2\">" + awardCategory + 
"</div>"));
tblCellLeft.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"style3\">" + awardNomWon + 
"</div>"));
tblCellLeft.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"style4\">" + "<img src=" + 
awardLogo.Replace(",", "") + "</div>"));

// add left cell to row
tblRow.Cells.Add(tblCellLeft);

if (rightIndexer < x) // if this item exists in the collection (prevent bug with odd 
number of awards)
{


// get the values
awardYear = listItemCollection[rightIndexer]["Title"].ToString();
awardCategory = listItemCollection[rightIndexer]["Category"].ToString();
awardNomWon = listItemCollection[rightIndexer]["NominatedWon"].ToString();

if (listItemCollection[rightIndexer]["Logo"] != null)
    awardLogo = (string)listItemCollection[rightIndexer]["Logo"];


// add to right cell
//Values for the right column
tblCellRight.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"style1\">" + awardYear + 
"</div>"));
tblCellRight.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"style2\">" + awardCategory 
+ "</div>"));
tblCellRight.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"style3\">" + awardNomWon + 
"</div>"));
tblCellRight.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"style4\">" + "<img src=" + 
awardLogo.Replace(",", "") + "</div>"));

//add right cell to row
tblRow.Cells.Add(tblCellRight);

}

// add row to table
tbl.Rows.Add(tblRow);

}

PlaceHolder6.Controls.Add(tbl); // add table outside of loop 
}
catch (Exception err)
{
PlaceHolder3.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(err.ToString()));
}

}
}



});
```

However this now brings another issue. The values returned are not sorted in the proper order in other words for some reason the latest list item is being pushed to the bottom where it should be a t the top. The other values get displayed in the correct order.

Anyone have any suggestions to get this sorted in proper order? It will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Have gotten this fixed now using the following caml query for the sorting: SPList awardsList = web.Lists["Awards"];                     

SPQuery q = new SPQuery();
q.Query="<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' /></OrderBy>";

SPListItemCollection listItemCollection = awardsList.Items.GetItems(q);

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want all your results in one table?

In which case you want to make sure you're only declaring a new `Table` *once*. To do this, declare your table *before* you begin your `foreach` loop.

```
Table tbl = new Table(); 
foreach (SPListItem oListItem in listItemCollection) 
{
   // get data
   // create cells & rows
   // insert data into cells, cells into rows, and rows into table
}
```

Comment: I get the same result. Basically what would be ideal would be to have each "Award" displaying side by side as it iterates through a loop. Havent yet managed to solve this one, its an iteresting one but it shouldbe so simple

Comment: Could you expand on 'not all list item values are being displayed'? Also, what output do you get when you simlply do something like: Console.WriteLine(oListItem["Year"].ToString()) for each oListItem? That would be a simple way of determining whether the collection is actually filled how you're expecting it to be.

Comment: Sure, I have 11 items in the list but only 8 are returned. Also they are repeated. I do get values when using Console.WriteLine(oListItem["Year"].ToString()) which is weird.

Comment: trying to see now if it can be done using a simpler loop. Hopefully

Comment: I would guess then that it's something to do with the way you're constructing your Table or how you're adding it to your PlaceHolder. Try adding a <div id="my_div" runat="server"/> to your page and add the tables into that without the mod condition. See if you get all 11 tables displayed first and work from there.